# Почему pascal неправильно перемножает матрицу

Tags: pascal

Даны две действительные квадратные матрицы порядка 10 и 20. В строках с отрицательным элементом на главной диагонали найти произведение всех элементов.

Все сделал, вроде работает, но при расширении диапазона выдает нереальное или маленькое число. В чем ошибка? Помогите, препод даже не хочет смотреть нерабочую прогу!

```
Const n =   20;

Type matr =   array [1..n, 1..n] Of integer;

    vek =   array[1..n] Of LongInt;

Var 
    A,B:   matr;

    VA,VB:   vek;


Procedure wwod(Var A: matr; k,p: byte);

Var i,j:   byte;

Begin

    Writeln('Ввод матрицы ',k,'-го порядка');

    randomize;

    For i:= 1 To k Do

        Begin

            For j:= 1 To p Do

                Begin

                    A[i,j] := random(10)-4;

                    Write(A[i,j]:2,' ');

                End;

            readln;

        End;


End;

Procedure proizv(Var A: matr; k,p: byte; Var VA: vek);


Var i,j:   byte;

    v,f:   integer; 

Begin

    For i:= 1 To k Do
        Begin

            f := j;

            For j:=1  To p Do

                If i=j Then If A[i,j]<0 

                Then
                    Begin

                        Begin
                            v := 1;

                            For f:=1 To p Do

                                v := v*A[i,f]

                        End;
                        Writeln('Произведение элементов ', i, ' строки - ',v);

                    End
                Else
                    Begin

                        Writeln('На главной диагонали находится положительный элемент');
                        break;
                    End;

        End;
    Readln;
End;
Begin

    wwod(A, 10, 10);

    proizv(A,10,10,VA);

    wwod(B, 20, 20);

    proizv(B,20,20,VB);


End.
```

Comment: не надо винить в этом Pascal

Comment: отформатируйте код. кнопка 101010

Comment: подскажи где ошибка

Comment: У Вас, что, действительно так много пустых строк в коде?

Comment: нет, это не форматировался код на сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, это связано с переполнением `integer`. Даже `longint` может не хватить, потому что пять в двадцатой степени равно `95 367 431 640 625`.

Comment: что делать?

Comment: использовать `extended` или длинную арифметику.

Comment: это как? нам про это не говорили. скажи как или дай название книги в которой про это пишется

Comment: @rentscan Кстати  
   
    For i:= 1 To k Do
      Begin
      f := j;
      For j:=1  To p Do
        If i=j Then If A[i,j]<0 then
          ...
можно заменить на 

    for i := 1 to k do
      if a[i, i] < 0 then
          ...

Comment: так не всегда выполняется для всех строк матрицы

Comment: прочитайте комментарий внимательнее. Зачем Вам два цикла, если нужно проверить только диагональные элементы. `a[i, i]` - это число на диагонали.